# apt: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.5.90

Tags: apt

I did a whole system update and then a distribution upgrade. After install I ran apt-get update and started to see some errors. Tried to troubleshoot the dependency issues by hand but I have had little success. Now any apt-get command throws this error.

```
apt: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.5.90: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Even I forced the update `sudo apt-get -f upgrade` and still not working.

Here's my `$ dpkg -l libapt-pkg.so.5.90` output :

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libapt-pkg.so.5.90
```

Any idea will be appreciated